# Mysql 8.0 with Letsencrypt SSL on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, apache2, mysql, ssl, letsencrypt

I installed a Letsencrypt SSL certificate on my Ubuntu 20.4 VPN server and it works. Now, I am trying to configure mysql on this server for SSL. I read many relating posts that deal with the same issue and I spent many hours to fix it, without success.

These are the steps I did:

- I copied the files cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem and privkey.pem into /var/lib/mysql.
  These are the same files that I used for the SSL configuration of my
  domain.
- The configuration in mysql was not clear. I tried different combinations in [mysql] and [mysqld]. The one I expected to be correct, did not work: `ssl_ca=/var/lib/mysql/cert.pem`,`ssl_cert=/var/lib/mysql/chain.pem`,`ssl_key=/var/lib/mysql/privkey.pem`

  Only this configuration works without throwing an error. Note: fullchain.pem contains the certificates from cert.pem and chain.pem. In /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d:

  ```
  [mysqld]

  ssl_cert=/var/lib/mysql/fullchain.pem

  ssl_key=/var/lib/mysql/privkey.pem
  ```

I can connect to mysql locally from my server and when checking the ssl attributes, I get:

(I list only the variables with values )

```
| Variable_name                       | Value                        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| have_openssl                        | YES                          |                       
| have_ssl                            | YES                          |
| performance_schema_show_processlist | OFF                          |
| ssl_cert                            | /var/lib/mysql/fullchain.pem |                           |
| ssl_fips_mode                       | OFF                          |
| ssl_key                             | /var/lib/mysql/privkey.pem
```

When I run `mysql > \s`, I get:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.21 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          66
Current database:
Current user:           someUser@someIP
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             maraxai.de via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
```

When I run `$ openssl s_client -connect maraxai.de:3306 -servername maraxai.de`, I expect to get the same result as with `$ openssl s_client -connect maraxai.de:443 -servername maraxai.de`, i.e. the complete certificate chain with the successful handshake but instead, I get:

```
139990121219392:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:331:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 302 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Some posts suggested that the line `SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 302 bytes` suggests that the SSL handshake has been started but aborted since the server returns something that is not expected.

To further check I use `openssl s_client -connect maraxai.de:3306 -servername maraxai.de -starttls mysql`. The first section tells me about `error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate` and `error:num=21:the server certificate is not verified`  for the server certificate `(depth:0)`. Further, I see only one certificate (cert.pem). The intermediate certificates of chain.pem are not listed. This is weird since I use fullchain.pem which is a concatenation of the certificates in chain.pem and cert.pem.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = maraxai.de
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = maraxai.de
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = maraxai.de
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//MIIF...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = maraxai.de

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2027 bytes and written 448 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: B157BD91FF0A458D6A546C26CB5665C95CD88B99CE6C66A5D98783642C39EFA4
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: CB807FC16CE11EB47FE7BDDD99C71A5AAF1AE5CDC600A127230E914AFC4AE1018A34F72F44741D2440EB4917D5DDD0D7
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    // ...0000 - 00e0


    Start Time: 1645286635
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
2▒▒#08S01Got timeout reading communication packetsread:errno=0
```

To check if issuers and subjects of the certificates are set correctly, I run:

`openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile fullchain.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout`

Everything looks ok here:

```
subject=CN = maraxai.de
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

subject=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
issuer=C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1

subject=C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
issuer=O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

Also, for privkey.pem, I changed the key format to PKCS#1 to get the correct header `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` with the command `$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out privkey.pem`.

I have no idea how to further investigate this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SSL certificates and port 443 are generally applied to Apache, not MySQL. Have you configured MySQL to listen to both 3306 and 443? Is the goal to have external machines connect to this database over SSL rather than through a more common secure method, such as SSH tunnel? 

Comment: Yes, I need an external connection. I want to run a Nodejs application on my domain, a questionnaire. The questions are stored in MySQL, as well as the answers. On completion a PDF will be generated which will be sent via email to the user. The server listens on port 443 for Apache and on port 3306 for MySQL.

Comment: I have to correct myself: external mysql connection works. I get: 
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Connection:       maraxai.de via TCP/IP
TCP port:               3306